# How can I load and display ASPX pages dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, plugins, webforms

My business wants to be able to have our main website load a handful of WebForms pages without recompilation of the website.

At first I'm thinking plugin.  So I created a tiny class which has a couple of abstract housekeeping methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// ABC to support dynamic loading of Reports pages which inherit from this.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ReportsPageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this to return the menu name of the page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public abstract string friendlyName();
}
```

The other developer(s) will inherit their ASPX pages on my class.  Their web application project compiles to a DLL.  That/those DLL(s) are copied into my plugins subdirectory.

In the main website, when a certain page loads, I scan the plugin directory for DLLs, load each, get their types, filter for the support of my base class and return the list:

```
public static List<Testbed.ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase> loadDlls()
{
    List<Testbed.ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase> retval = new List<ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase>();
    string reportsDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins", "Reports");
    if (!Directory.Exists(reportsDir))
    {
        try {Directory.CreateDirectory(reportsDir); }
        Catch (Exception) { //Log the exception }
        return retval;
    }

    string targetBaseTypeFullName = typeof(Testbed.ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase).FullName;
    string[] filespecs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(reportsDir, "*.dll");
    foreach (String filespec in filespecs)
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(filespec);
        Type[] tt = ass.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type t in tt)
        {
            Type bt = t.BaseType;
            if (bt == null) continue;
            if (bt.FullName == targetBaseTypeFullName)
            {
                Testbed.ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase dynInstance = (Testbed.ReportsPageBase.ReportsPageBase)ass.CreateInstance(t.FullName, false);
                if (dynInstance == null) continue;
                retval.Add(dynInstance);
            }
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

I'm targetting IIS7 in integrated mode.  In the web.config file, I set up routing:

In Global.asax, I elect to route, oh, say, "RoutedReport.aspx" to a RouteHandler I will define next:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    // ...

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        // ...

        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=VS.90%29.aspx
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add("MyRoutedRouteName", new Route("RoutedReport.aspx", new MyRouteHandler("~/AnythingCanGoHere.aspx")));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then I declare an IRouteHandler as per MSDN suggestion, named according the Route added above:

```
public class MyRouteHandler : System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler
{
    public MyRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }


    public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }


    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // What now???
    }
}
```

I can take one of those dynamically loaded instances and return it since the page inherits from IHttpHandler.  But when I do, nothing is rendered.  **Where do I go from here?**

Comment: I think your best solution is to call out the time conflict, and ask the government what they want to do about it.  Nothing good can come from trying to override government quality control procedures.  If the thing crashes, your ass is grass.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Maybe whisper "healthcare.gov" where they can hear it - you may get enough time to do the job properly.